# Is there any way i can nullify all $this variables without assigning null line by line?

Tags: php, class, variables, this

Is there any way i can nullify all $this variables without assigning null line by line?

```
   public function refresh(){
    unset($this);
}
```

The unset does not work..

Answer (score 0):

You can't unset($ths) while you're in $this; otherwise you'd end up nowhere.

```
$this->propertyA = $this->propertyB = $this->propertyC = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

why you want to do this? simple unset your instance of the class you are working with, and everything inside is gone

```
$a = new SomeClass();
$a->someVar = "1";
$a->someOtherVar = "2";
unset($a);
```

but don't forget to create a new instance, if you want to continue `$a`
However, this will reset all values to their default value set in the property definition:

```
foreach (get_class_vars(get_class($this)) as $name => $def){ 
  $this->$name = $def;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try looping through each field and unset them one by one. Like this:

```
    function refresh() {
       foreach($this as $key => $value) {
           unset($this->$key);
       }
    }
```

NOTE: I can't test it now this code is untested.

Comment: a class is not an array in terms of access.